# NSPredicate for Regular Search

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I am using NSPredicate for the performing Search as it does on iPhone when we search for any app.

I have say for example 4 keywords

1. Deccan
2. New Delhi
3. Ahmedabad
4. Salaam Delhi

I have tried creating a predicate with

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyword BEGINSWITH[c] 'd'"`
It gives me **Deccan** as output.
But the problem is I want each word starting with **d** So from the above example I need output as 
**Deccan, New Delhi, Salaam Delhi** but **NOT Ahmedabad**

Stucked in this issue from hours. tried contains, matches but my bad luck..

Any help towards right path will really be appreciated..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks guys for your responses
Here's what I come up with

```
NSString *matchString =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*",searchText];
NSString *predicateString = @"keyword MATCHES[c] %@";
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString, matchString];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two way for you

1. Divide the steing by ' ' and use your `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyword BEGINSWITH[c] 'd'"]`
2. Or, the better way, to use two predicates :

`predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyword BEGINSWITH[c] 'd' 
OR keyword contains[c]       ' d'"]`// `i mean,'space+d'`

So you'll it will satisfy both of possible cases.

Comment: thanks @Nikita. It works with single static character. but take an example where the characters are coming dynamic. If I type d it comes up with three options and when i type 'del' it displays keyword 2 and 4

Answer (score 0):

Consider "like" and "matches."  Note, however, that these are relatively expensive operations, and can take considerable time on large data sets.

In this example, I assume what you want is to match if any space-separated word in  starts with "d"

This checks to see if keyword either begins with 'd' or has a sequence with a  followed by 'd'

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(keyword BEGINSWITH[c] 'd') OR (keyword LIKE[c] '* d')"]
```

This one uses a regular expression, which is very similar (use the regex that best suites your situation:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyword MATCHES[c] '^d.*|.*\\sd.*'"]
```